# How to construct specific list implementation without knowing which one it is?

Tags: java, list, generics

I want to create a list of the same type as the one passed in the parameter, so if givenList is an Arraylist then Copy should be one, if it is a linkedList then Copy should be one etc.

Is there a way to do this without manually checking the type List has using instanceof?

```
public static <E> void sorter (List<E> givenList) {
    List<E> copy = new ?????
```

Comment: Assuming it has a public no-arg ctor, `givenList.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance()`

Comment: Usually it is not needed. Can you tell us more about why you need to know the exact type of the list? Maybe it can be solved using only the List type.

Comment: Change your signature to accept an empty list to be used by `sorter`, or a `Supplier<List>` to create a new empty list.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. You can try something like `givenList.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance()`. This is not at all guaranteed to work. More generally if you want a  copy, `givenList.clone()` is a much better idea.

Comment: List doesn't extend Cloneable, so it would need instanceof and a cast

Comment: I haven't seen anyone recommend java's `clone` method in a long time...

Comment: Yes, `clone()` is an extremely bad option. `givenList.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance()` is an even worse option. It's the best choice amongst 2 extremely bad ones.

Comment: In fact, it's not possible to cast to plain old Cloneable and achieve what you want anyway. Cloneable's (poor) implementation requires the target class (e.g. ArrayList) to widen the access to public. So without knowing the concrete type, `clone()` isn't invokable. By reflection, yes, but at that point you may as well look for a no-arg ctor.